# WPF - Unable to shutdown application after adding splash window to the project

Tags: wpf, splash-screen, mainwindow

I am unable to shutdown my WPF application on closing the main window. Just facing this issue after adding new window (splash screen) to my project.
Below is the newly added code in App.xaml.cs

```
SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen();
splash.Show();
MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
this.MainWindow = main;
Thread.Sleep(2000);           
splash.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the `Shutdownmode` of the `App` to `ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose`:

```
ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
```

Then the app should shutdown when you close `main` (assuming you actually show it first).

Comment: I am only showing 2 screens. First splash screen then main window but this is not helping. Main window gets closed but application keeps on running in background process.

Comment: Not if you set `ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose` to `OnMainWindowClose` and set `this.MainWindow` to the window that you are closing.

Comment: If you add `main.Show()` to your sample code, run the app and close `main`, the process dies as expected.

Comment: Adding `main.show()` explicitly opens 2 main windows screen. And yes process kills as expected.

Comment: No, because I am now seeing 2 main windows instead of 1.

Comment: You may be seeing two windows but there is only one *main*  window. What's your issue?